# Im trying to make a automated script, that auto sends emails with an pdf attachment

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script

This is my script

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 8;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Thomas.pdf')
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {

    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message,
       {attachments: file.next().getBlob()};
  }
}
```

I keep getting the Error: Missing ) after argument list. (line 17, file "SendEmail") Can anybody see whats the error is, or guide me in right direction?

Comment: Mhh just look for the closing `)` for `MailApp.sendEmail(`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite straightforward: add the missing `)`.

Replace

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message,
       {attachments: file.next().getBlob()};
```

by

```
MailApp.sendEmail(
   emailAddress, subject, message,
   {attachments: file.next().getBlob()}
);
```